# Unable to resolve service for type 'BLL.DatabaseContext'

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

Please Help me How can i connect to DB
My Project Structure Is Like This
**GymViewModel**

```
public class UserLogin
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
    }
```

**GymInterface**

```
public interface ILogin 
    {
        IEnumerable<UserLogin> GetUserLoginDetails();
    }
```

**BLL**

```
Public Class LoginRepo : ILogin{
 private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;
        private readonly DatabaseContext _context;

        public LoginRepo(DatabaseContext context, IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            _context = context;
            _configuration = configuration;

        }
 public IEnumerable<UserLogin> GetUserLoginDetails()
        {
            var x = from n in _context.UserLogin
                    select n;
            return x;
        }
}
```

**ApiController**
Here i Consume My Interface With the help of DatabaseContext i try to connect my db but im Getting Error While Executing The Command

```
[ApiController]
    public class LoginController : ControllerBase
    {
     private readonly DatabaseContext _context;
            private readonly ILogin _ILogin;
            public LoginController(ILogin ILogin)
            {
                _ILogin = ILogin;
            }
            public IEnumerable<UserLogin> GetUserLoginDetails()
            {
              return  _ILogin.GetUserLoginDetails();
            }
```

Comment: By default `IConfiugration` isn't registered with the IoC container. Neither should you need to inject it. Use the [Options pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/options?view=aspnetcore-2.2) instead

Comment: In Startup.cs in ConfigureServices method `services.AddScoped<ILogin>(provider => new LoginRepo(configuration, dbcontext))`

Comment: @options no not working do u have any other solution

Comment: Unable to resolve service for type 'BLL.DatabaseContext'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to register the `DatabaseContext` class with the DI container, which you can do in ASP.NET Core from the `Startup::ConfigureServices` method:

```
services.AddScoped<DatabaseContext>();
```

> The actual registration depends on what `DatabaseContext` actually depends on.